# eclipselink JPQL error : The order by item is not a valid expression

Tags: eclipselink, jpql

Any idea why JPQL is complaining with with the error below?
The order by expression looks good to me...
I'm using eclipselink 2.7.4

Thanks

```
   public Task getLastUpdatedTask() {
        String queryString = "SELECT tk FROM task tk WHERE tk.last_modified <= :searchDate ORDER BY tk.last_modified ASC, LIMIT 1";
        Query query = entityManager.createQuery(queryString);
        query.setParameter("searchDate", getSearchDate());
        return (Task)query.getSingleResult();
    }

    private Calendar getSearchDate() {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
        cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -2);
        return cal;
    }

ix-data-collector_1     | 146845 [scheduling-1] ERROR o.s.s.s.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler - Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task
mix-data-collector_1     | java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager:
mix-data-collector_1     | Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [SELECT tk FROM task tk WHERE tk.last_modified <= :searchDate ORDER BY tk.last_modified ASC, LIMIT 1].
mix-data-collector_1     | [92, 99] The order by item is not a valid expression.
mix-data-collector_1     |      at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1746)
```

Comment: Limit 1 isn’t valid in jpql

Comment: Thanks! I've fixed my problem by removing the limit from the query and using query.setMaxResults(1) instead. If the error would have been mode descriptive in this regards i would have figured it out easier.